# Can you create MiniZinc models dynamically using the Python interface?

Tags: minizinc

I would like to know if it is possible to create a MiniZinc model using the Python interface. As I saw on the documentation you could add the model as a string, but that would be no different to an external MiniZinc file that you call afterwards.

What I would like is to create a model that uses variables that depend on some previous computation, therefore not a fixed value that I could provide before running the Python code. Would that be possible ?

Answer (score 1):

The MiniZinc Python package currently does communicate with the minizinc executable through the use of files. As you said MiniZinc Python does also allow you to supply (parts of) models through the use of strings. **There is no problem generating these files or string dynamically**, they will simply be parsed by the minizinc executable at compilation time.

Note, that there are many options to generate MiniZinc model strings in Python:

- You can conditionally append the model string depending on other Python code.
- You can use interleaf the model strings with Python executions. For example, using f-strings.
- Or you can use one of the many templating packages available in Python.

For most applications this seems to be sufficient. The overhead of creating the strings/files and parsing them in the MiniZinc executable is in the order of milliseconds on most systems and is insignificant compared to solving (and flattening) time.

For rapidly evolving models, like for example running an LNS with smaller neighbourhoods, even this small overhead might be a problem. We are still working on solutions to avoid this overhead, but they are currently not ready for the general public yet.